# c# - Add terminal process output to a list to use on other classes

Tags: c#, terminal

I read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506985/c-opening-the-terminal-process-and-pass-commands) to start a terminal process and modified a little code to get terminal output and use that output in other classes.

My code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace runTerminal
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static List<string> ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c \" " + command + " \"";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();

            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
                Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
                output.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            }

            return output;
        }

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> result = ExecuteCommand("sudo nginx -t");
            Console.WriteLine(result); // return null
        }
    }
}
```

But the output I got after executing commands is always null. Do I miss something?

Comment: have you stepped through the code using the debugger..? what does the Arguments look like when stepping past this line in the debugger
`proc.StartInfo.Arguments =` can you show us..?

Comment: Can't explain the null... But you're trying to print an collection to console, doesn't this require a loop?

Comment: @DanielShillcock I am sorry when printing an collection without using a loop. It is my fault. But the real issue when I call  twice with `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
            Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
            output.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine());
        }
```

That's a double read. You call `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` two times in sequence. The first line will be printed, but then you attempt to read another line and store it in `output`. Do the following:

```
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
            var read = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(read);
            output.Add(read);
        }
```

You also print it wrong. Since `output` is `List<string>()` you could do

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

To print it.

Comment: You are right! I am wrong when calling twice with `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine()`. I fixed my code following your comment and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to iterate over the List of strings:

```
 public static void Main (string[] args)
 {
   List<string> result = ExecuteCommand("sudo nginx -t");
   foreach (string output in result)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(output); 
   }
 }
```